# Exit Phonegap-Android Test App On Exit Button?

Tags: android, cordova

I am new to Phonegap, My app has login page with user name, password, login button and exit button. when i click on exit button, i want to close the App,

```
<body>
<script>

 function exitFromApp()
            {
               navigator.app.exitApp();
            }
</script>
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
      <a href="login.html"  data-theme="b">Login</a>
      <h1>Bird on Tree</h1>
      <button type="button2" onclick="exitFromApp()">Exit</button>
</div>
```

The above is what i tried to quit app on button click, It works only on when am not logged into app, if i logged in and try to quit app on button click it shows this error

```
03-03 01:58:10.457: E/Web Console(1222): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'exitApp' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/main.html:5
```

Please help me how to solve this issue

Answer (score 4):

Try this code.

```
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

            function onLoad()
            {
               document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
            }

            function exitFromApp()
            {
                if (navigator.app) {
                   navigator.app.exitApp();
                }
                else if (navigator.device) {
                    navigator.device.exitApp();
                }
            }

        </script>

    <body onload="onLoad();">
       <button name="buttonClick" onclick="exitFromApp()">Click Me!</button>
    </body>
```

Comment: check now. I edit the answer. This should work using phonegap version 2.5.0 and onwards.

Answer (score 1):

Use code below to exit the application.

```
exitApp:function() {   
    app.exitApp();
}
```